# ConfigurationError: Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of PyMongo requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6)

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I am trying to build an application with mongoDB and Python Flask. While running the application, I am getting below error:

> ConfigurationError: Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports wire version 0,
>   but this version of PyMongo requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6).

Can any one help me in this?

Thanks,
Balwinder

Comment: Please specify what version of MongoDB you are using.

Comment: db version v1.8.2

Comment: I think i need to upgrade to 2.6. Is it so, @MikaS?

Comment: That's what the error message claims. You can probably upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you change the server from ubuntu software center follow step

1- Search Software & update in ubuntu software center

2- Select `Download from` select `Other` then right side select `Select best server` it will take some time if it's complete 
[image]

try to re install mongodb from this command

**Step 1**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```

**Step 2**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**step 3**

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 27):

It's pretty annoying and weird issue.

But this problem is solved with just downgrading **`pymongo`** library for me.

```
pip install pymongo==3.4.0
```

Found answer in this : http://d-prototype.com/archives/10939

Comment: This solution worked, but led to broken code given slight function differences between 3.4.0 and the most recent version (at this time, 3.10.1)

Answer (score 5):

I am having the same issue using version 2.4.10 on a Raspberry Pi 3. I found interesting information here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26715

According to the above Jira task, it seems that this is a bug of MongoDB that was fixed in version 3.4. However, I found [that comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67918/unable-to-install-mongodb-3-4-on-pi-3) stating that 3.4 is not supported on Raspbian because it is a 32-bits OS. [This is confirmed here](http://koenaerts.ca/compile-and-install-mongodb-on-raspberry-pi/)... we can only install 3.2 on Raspbian now apparently.

An alternative would be to install 64bits SuSE on the Pi or run MongoDB 3.4 in Docker.

Let me know if you have found something else...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. `sudo pip3 uninstall pymongo`
2. `sudo apt-get install python3-pymongo`

I hope that works for someone else, regards.

Comment: sudo installing python libraries is considered unsafe. please be aware.

Comment: This worked, but for some reason after uninstalling, running `pip3 freeze | grep pymongo` revealed that version 3.5.1 was leftover...I had to `pip3 uninstall pymongo` TWICE, then `pip3 install pymongo==3.4.0` for my code to work without this error. I did not use apt-get to install pymongo 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

loose_srv_version = LooseVersion(client.server_info()['version'])

loose_driver_version = LooseVersion(PyMongoVersion)

```
if loose_srv_version >= LooseVersion('3.2') and loose_driver_version <= LooseVersion('3.2'):
    module.fail_json(msg=' (Note: you must use pymongo 3.2+ with MongoDB >= 3.2)')

elif loose_srv_version >= LooseVersion('3.0') and loose_driver_version <= LooseVersion('2.8'):
    module.fail_json(msg=' (Note: you must use pymongo 2.8+ with MongoDB 3.0)')

elif loose_srv_version >= LooseVersion('2.6') and loose_driver_version <= LooseVersion('2.7'):
    module.fail_json(msg=' (Note: you must use pymongo 2.7+ with MongoDB 2.6)')

elif LooseVersion(PyMongoVersion) <= LooseVersion('2.5'):
    module.fail_json(msg=' (Note: you must be on mongodb 2.4+ and pymongo 2.5+ to use the roles param)')
```