# MongoDB Node JS : MongoServerSelectionError

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new with `mongoDB` and `NodeJS` and I have this error on my Raspberry Pi. However, I don't have any error while running it on Ubuntu.

Here is my code :

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost/logs",{useUnifiedTopology : true},function(error,db) {
    if(error) throw(error);
    console.log("connected");
});
```

And here is the error I got:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: Server at localhost:27017 reports maximum wire version 0, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6)
    at Timeout.waitQueueMember.timer.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/pi/monitoring/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:448:30)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

Does anyone knows how to solve the version problem?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which version of `mongoDB` are you using?

Comment: I installed mongodb with
`sudo apt-get install mongo-db`
`npm install mongodb`

Here are the versions installed :
`root@retropie:/home/pi/monitoring# mongo --version`
`MongoDB shell version: 2.4.14`
`root@retropie:/home/pi/monitoring# npm view mongodb version`
`3.5.2`

Comment: Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060354/configurationerror-server-at-127-0-0-127017-reports-wire-version-0-but-this-v

Comment: Well I don't know how to properly uninstall MongoDB to install the 2.6 version... Can you help me please ?

Comment: Try: `npm uninstall mongodb` and `npm i mongodb@2.6` but I'm not sure that's what you need to be doing. You may have more success in downgrading your NodeJS version

Comment: Here is a similar issue: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=237324 I don't know what your configuration file looks like but this post may help with diagnosing your issue